# Stripe webhook to tell when a subscription lapses

Tags: stripe-payments, webhooks

So I am trying to hook into the Stripe API to catch when a customer's subscription actually ends to I can revoke access for the product.

I tried to use the customer.subscription.deleted event, however it seems like this event triggers when a customer hits cancel and does not actually wait for their subscription time to run out. Is there an event I can use to capture when a customer's subscription actually lapses?

Otherwise, it seems like I will have to program a way to check again on their cancellation date if they resubscribed or if their sub did indeed lapse.

Thank you for any and all help.

Answer (score 2):

If you [update a subscription](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/update) and set the [cancel_at_period_end](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/update#update_subscription-cancel_at_period_end) parameter to true, Stripe will keep the subscription active until the end of the period at which point it will cancel automatically. In this scenario you would get:

- A [customer.subscription.updated](https://stripe.com/docs/api/events/types#event_types-customer.subscription.created) event when the subscription is updated to cancel at the end of the period.
- A [customer.subscription.deleted](https://stripe.com/docs/api/events/types#event_types-customer.subscription.deleted) event at the end of the period when the subscription is cancelled automatically by Stripe

If you cancel the subscription immediately by calling the [Subscription Delete](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/cancel) method, then Stripe will only emit the [customer.subscription.deleted](https://stripe.com/docs/api/events/types#event_types-customer.subscription.deleted) event.

This is explained in detail here: https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/cancel#events

Comment: I currently have a webook setup on customer.subscription.deleted. I see that if I manually cancel a subscription, the customer.subscription.deleted hook is called. However, this does not seem to do what Stripe states with "at the end of the period". It is getting triggered immediately when the customer cancels, even though their subscription doesn't end for a month. The way the event is worded makes it seem like it is after the subscription date ends, but this is not the case.